# Overriding Block class from extension

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks, overrides

I need to override a Block from an external extension.
This is my setup with the necessary files:

The **module** file (*app/etc/modules/Mynamespace_Mymodulename.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mynamespace_Mymodulename>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <mgs_auction />
      </depends>
    </Mynamespace_Mymodulename>
  </modules>
</config>
```

The **config** file (*app/code/local/Mynamespace/Auction/etc/config.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mynamespace_Mymodulename>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Mynamespace_Mymodulename>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <auction>
          <rewrite>
            <auction>Mynamespace_Auction_Block_Auction</auction>
          </rewrite>
        </auction>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

The block path from the extension:

> app/code/local/Mgs/Auction/Block/Auction.php

and my structure:

> app/code/local/Mynamespace/Auction/Block/Auction.php

with following content:

```
class Mynamespace_Auction_Block_Auction extends Mgs_Auction_Block_Auction {
    public function ... () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Tested it but the original block class from the extension is still used. I guess something is missing or wrong titled in the config.xml. Could you help me out?

**Edit:**

The original **config.xml** from the extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mgs_Auction>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </Mgs_Auction>
    </modules>
    ...
   <global>
        <blocks>
            <auction>
                 <class>Mgs_Auction_Block</class>
            </auction>
        </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you post the original module `config.xml` file ?

Comment: Hi @Raphael. Is there a specific part that you like to see? It's a huge file and i don't know if everything is necessary.

Comment: @Raphael I added a part from the config.xml of the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you need to respect the case, for example in your `app/etc/modules` XML file you should replace:

```
<mgs_auction />
```

With:

```
<Mgs_Auction />
```

On top of that **your block is not properly placed and declared.**

Indeed you declared your module as `Mynamespace_Mymodulename` but your block is declared under `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Auction/Block/Auction.php` whereas it should be `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodulename/Block/Auction.php`

On top of that ensure your module is in the `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodulename` folder and change the following in your `config.xml` :

```
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <auction>
          <rewrite>
            <auction>Mynamespace_Auction_Block_Auction</auction>
          </rewrite>
        </auction>
    </blocks>
  </global>
```

With:

```
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <auction>
          <rewrite>
            <auction>Mynamespace_Mymodulename_Block_Auction</auction>
          </rewrite>
        </auction>
    </blocks>
  </global>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your great help! Your solution did the job. As addition, of course i also had to changed the class name to: `Mynamespace_Mymodulename_Block_Auction`

Answer (score 2):

You can just set your class to extend the class you are trying to override:

```
class Mynamespace_Auction_Block_Auction extends Mgs_Auction_Block_Auction
```

Set your layout update xml in config.xml file

```
<frontend>
    ...
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mymodule>
                <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    ...
</frontend>
```

and remove in `mymodule.xml` layout, origin block and replace on your block
for example.

```
<module_controller_action>
  <reference name='content'>
     <remove name='oldblock' />
     <block type="your_namespace/your_type" name="oldblock" template="oldblock.phtml">
  </reference>
</module_controller_action>
```

Comment: Hello @Naumov. Thanks for your help but I don't know if this would fix my problem. I need to override a function in the block class called "Auction.php".

Answer (score 1):

Rewrites are tricky.
There are several options what could go wrong. As a first guess - in the config.xml, in rewrite section, in path global->blocks->rewrite->**auction** - maybe should be the mgs_auction, as I presume that this is the name module is called. To check what this tag should be, check Msg Auction's (module you're rewriting) config.xml, the section where it declares blocks:

`<global>
   <blocks>
       <the_needed_name_is_here>
       </the_needed_name_is_here>
   </blocks>
</global>`

If this doesn't help, check that this block is used, because if it is it's child, then the rewrite don't work, as I am sure you are aware of.

Comment: Hello @Wladyslaw. Thanks for your help. I tryed your proposal but no luck. I've added a part of the original config.xml. Maybe you have another clue.